# Поле для кода на сайте

Tags: javascript, html

Назрел такой вопрос, как сделать поле для кода на сайте, это ведь уже реализовано в библиотеках как я понимаю?

```
console.log('Поле с кодом, как тебя звать');
//на подобии такого поля, я просто не знаю как это даже называется
```

Буду рад любой помощи. любым подсказкам, хотя бы как это называется. Спасибо!

Конкретно вот такое поле интересует с нумерацией, и кнопкой выделить все, и подсветкой[image: Интересующее поле]

По наводке был использован highlight.js. Кто подскажет как им пользоваться? Вроде сделал так как написано , но что то не то все равно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.7.0/styles/default.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.7.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <pre><code class="html">
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="button"/>
    </form>
</code></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Учточни пожалуйста - прикрепи скрин, чего ты хочешь видеть. Я подумал про подсветку синтаксиса и ответил. Потом удалил, потому что тебе возможно нужен редактор кода?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, да именно с подсветкой синтаксиса, конкретно html интересует. А есть которые маломальское авторедактирование делают, отступы интересуют? Сейчас прикреплю

Comment: https://highlightjs.org . Про отступы - это называется "автоформотирование" - вроде тоже есть, но конкретно ничего не подскажу: скорее всего этот функционал встроен в такие плагины.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, спасибо за помощь! Буду вам еще более признателен если поможете разобраться с ним) Код прикрепил в вопросе, что то там не ладное...

Comment: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/ ,
http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1855  ,
`<code></code>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно экранировать html с помощью `&lt;` `&gt;` или с помощью `jQuery` перевести html в текст:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    $(block).text($(block).html());
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.7.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.7.0/styles/default.min.css">

<pre><code class="html">
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="button"/>
    </form>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: А есть возможность добавит функцию, или вручную добавляя в строку  некие операторы переносить строку и делать отступы? если у нас код в одну строку, то он так и отображается в строку